# Class inheritance and the virtual function table

Tags: c++

A simple hierarchy:

```
class X
{
public:
     virtual void test(){ printf("x\n");}
};

class Y : public X
{
public:
    virtual void test() { printf("y\n");}
};

class Z : public Y
{
public:
    void test() { printf("z\n");}
};
```

If I create an instance of z I would expect that this instance's vtable would point to z's test function no matter to which base I am going to cast it to:

```
Z myZ;
myZ.test();
((Y)myZ).test();
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Dynamic dispatch occur only when an object is accessed by a reference or a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you do an actual type conversion of `myZ`. By doing this the compiler will create a temporary object `(Y)myZ` of type `Y` and will use that to call it's `test` method.

A longer equivalent of your your code would be something like:

```
Z myZ;

Y tmp = Y(myZ);

tmp.test();
```

You can see that this happens if your `test` method modifies the object in any way. Then `((Y)myZ).test()` should not modify `myZ`.

As pointed out dynamic dispatch is only required to happen on pointer or reference.

In fact you cannot draw the distinction between pointer and no pointer, you could for example have have a trampoline method in `X` something like this, and it would still call `Y::test` despite you're using a pointer:

```
class X {
public:
    void call_test() {
        this->test();
    }
}
```

The fact that dynamic dispatch doesn't happen could be seen as more of a optimization technique. The compiler knows that `((Y)myZ)` will have the virtual table of `Y` and can therefore immediately call `Y::test`.

Answer (score 2):

```
((Y)myZ)
```

since `myZ` is not pointer it is slicing. So, `Y::test` will be called, since there is no information about `Z` here.

But you can use pointers (or references):

```
   Z* z = new Z();
   z->test();
   Y* y = z;
   y->test();
   delete z;
```

`z` will be printed twice.

Comment: So you are saying if my derived class is not  a pointer type, the vtable is not considered in the case above? Why does C++ treat pointer  and non pointer types differently? And in this case slicing means just cutting of all additional information that class z would add to class y?

Comment: @wanderameise No class is a pointer type. And C++ treats pointers and objects differently because that's the way C++ was designed. A pointer is a mechanism to access an object indirectly. When you call a method directly on an object, you know its exact type, why would the compiler plug in code to look in a function table for the method, instead of calling it directly?